# Is it possible to peek HttpClient's org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream?

Tags: java, httpclient, inputstream

I am trying to peek at an input stream contents from HttpClient, up to 64k bytes.

The stream comes from an HttpGet, nothing unusual about it:

`HttpGet requestGet = new HttpGet(encodedUrl);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(requestGet);
int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
  return httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
}`

The input stream it returns is of type `org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream`

Our use-case is such that we need to "peek" at the first (up to 64k) bytes of the input stream. I use an algorithm described here [How do I peek at the first two bytes in an InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148130/how-do-i-peek-at-the-first-two-bytes-in-an-inputstream?rq=1)

`PushbackInputStream pis = new PushbackInputStream(inputStream, DEFAULT_PEEK_BUFFER_SIZE);
    byte [] peekBytes = new byte[DEFAULT_PEEK_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = pis.read(peekBytes);
    if (read < DEFAULT_PEEK_BUFFER_SIZE) {
      byte[] trimmed = new byte[read];
      System.arraycopy(peekBytes, 0, trimmed, 0, read);
      peekBytes = trimmed;
    }
    pis.unread(peekBytes);`

When I use a ByteArrayInputStream, this works with no problem.

The Issue: When using the `org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream` I only get a small number of bytes at the beginning of the stream. usually around 400 bytes. When I expected up to 64k bytes.

I also tried using a `BufferedInputStream` where I read up to the first 64k bytes then call a `.reset()` but that doesn't work either. Same issue.

Why might this be? I do not think anything is closing the stream because if you call `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` I do get all the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [InputStream#read(byte[] b,int off,int len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)) contract:

> Reads up to len bytes of data from the input stream into an array of
>   bytes. An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, **but a
>   smaller number may be read**. The number of bytes actually read is
>   returned as an integer

Instead of using this method, use `IOUtils.read` which reads until you get the number of bytes you requested in a loop.

Comment: aw dang it! any idea how to make it return more? do i just use the offset and make another request? are you sure that's not just saying that it will return less bytes if it doesn't have any more left?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure. You just need to keep on reading in a loop until the desired of amount of data has been received or end of stream is reached.

Comment: This did not work. `available()` returns 0. It thinks the stream is empty so adding the loop that you suggested did nothing.

Comment: instead of using `read` from the InputStream, using `IOUtils.read()` (which has the loop we were discussing) works!. so disregard my previous comment.